# which regulator should be used in converting 12v to 7.2v

Tags: voltage-regulator

i have a 12v power supply and i need to reduce the voltage to 7.2v for a rs360sh motor and which voltage regulator should i use.??
the motor takes 0.33A at no load,4.3A at max efficiency and 8.3A at stalling torque.i tried other regulators but it has only small current capacity.also please give the connection circuit.

Comment: It sounds that it would probably best to use a dedicated 7.2V 10A primary switched power supply in the first place. "Dropping" those 4.8V@8A is a massive loss even with an efficient DC/DC regulator. What kind of PSU is your 12V one?

Comment: You don't have to drop the voltage at all for a motor, just run it at a reduced PWM duty cycle.

Comment: -1 for "please do it fast"

Comment: 7807, if you can find it

Comment: @Somesh: No, not even close.  Show me a 780x regulator that can handle 40 W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a linear regulator like you are asking about will waste lots of power.  Perhaps you don't care about the power loss in this application, but dealing with the heat will not be easy.

12 V - 7.2 V = 4.8 V, which is the voltage the regulator will need to drop.  That times the current is the power it will dissipate, which is 4.8 V x 8.3 A = 40 W.  Yikes!  You're not going to find a drop in regulator that can dissipate 40 W.

A better answer is to run the motor directly from 12 V, but bring the effective voltage it sees down by pulsing the 12 V.  7.2 V / 12 V = 60%.  If you pulse the motor fast enough so that it can't "see" the individual pulses and these apply the 12 V 60% of the time, then the motor is effectively being driven with 7.2 V.  This concept is called *pulse width modulation* (PWM), and is a very common way to drive motors.  In effect, you are using a switching power supply to drive the motor, but that the motor is a integral part of the switcher.

For most motors, as long as the pulse frequency is a few 100 Hz, they will react to the average level and not the individual pulses.  However, individual coil windings and other parts of the motor may move very slightly in response to the rippling current.  These small motions don't effect the motor operation, but may cause unacceptable audible whine.  For this reason, motors are often driven with 25 kHz or so PWM, since that is above the hearing range of most people.  1 / 25 kHz = 40 µs, which would be the PWM period.  Since you want 60% duty cycle, the pulses would be on for 24 µs and off for 16 µs.

All you need is a low side switch transistor to cause the 12 V to be applied or not applied to the motor.  At this low voltage, you can probably find a FET that can be driven directly from a 5 V or maybe even 3.3 V logic signal.  Don't forget the reverse Schottky diode accross the motor to catch inductive kickback and keep it from blowing out the transistor.

Comment: SInce i'm new to electrical can u please tell me how to use PWM..can u please provide the relevant circuit..??

Comment: @Cyril: That's a bit much for a post here.  The PWM signal is just a ordinary digital signal like from a microcontroller.  Lots of them have PWM generators built in.  This signal is used to turn a FET on and off, which is connected between the motor's negative lead and ground.  The motor's positive lead goes to the 12 V supply.  There must be a Schottky diode accross the motor opposing the normal voltage.  This catches the kick back current when the motor is turned off.  There is much out there on "PWM" and "low side switch".